# How to update THREE material data?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to change the material of a objects based on a radio button selection. A color change works in my current example. Unfortunately it does not update the whole material.

How do I tell THREE to update its internal data accordingly?

**Materials**

```
  var lederfaserMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/lederfaser.jpg' );
  lederfaserMap.anisotropy = 16;
  lederfaserMap.wrapS = lederfaserMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  lederfaserMap.repeat.set( 5, 5 );


  var feinleinenMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/feinleinen.jpg' );
  feinleinenMap.anisotropy = 16;
  feinleinenMap.wrapS = feinleinenMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  feinleinenMap.repeat.set( 8, 8 );


  var material = {     
  "feinleinen-schwarz":     new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x222222, map: feinleinenMap, combine: THREE.MixOperation} ),
  "feinleinen-weiss":   new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, map: feinleinenMap, combine: THREE.MixOperation } ),
  "lederfaser-schwarz":     new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x222222, map: lederfaserMap, combine: THREE.MixOperation } ),
  }
```

**Update the Material here**

```
  var group = new THREE.Group();

loader.load('/models/object.js', function(geometry){
  var materialchange= new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material[ "feinleinen-schwarz" ]);
  materialchange.name = "materialchange";
  group.add( materialchange);
});  

  scene.add( group );



function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  TWEEN.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

**Function to get and update the material**

```
function colorTo (target, value){
      var target = scene.getObjectByName(target);
      var initial = new THREE.Color(target.material.color.getHex());
      var value = new THREE.Color(value.color.getHex());
      var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(initial).to(value, 500)
          .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut)
          .onUpdate(function(){
              target.material.color = initial;
          })
          .start();
  }
```

**Function to get the attribute of the checked radio button**

```
$("input[name=material]").change(function(event){
    if ($(this.checked)) {
        var targetColor = $(this).data("visual");
          colorTo("materialchange", material[targetColor]);
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to traverse the object to assign the new color to all of its sub-parts:

```
object.traverse ( function (child) {

    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
        child.material.color.copy = new_color;

}
```

Comment: the only mesh I see in your code is `materialchange` so I would do `materialchange.traverse ...`